# Element adjust width according to parent and siblings

Tags: html, css

I have set the parent div and its 3 children divs. Now, the 3rd child is hidden. I've set the width of the 1st child as 20% and wants the 2nd child to take the remaining width automatically without setting it explicitly. The 3rd child's width is 20% and when it's unhidden it should take its part of the parent's width while the 2nd should re-adjust its width accordingly.

```
<div id="parent" style="background-color: pink;">
    <div id="child1" style="background-color: gray; display: inline-block; width: 20%;">
        div1
    </div>

    <div id="child2" style="background-color: blue; display: inline-block">
        div2
    </div>

    <div id="child2" style="background-color: violet; display: hidden; width: 20%;">
        div3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want flexbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be implemented by flex layout. Here is the code snippet for your case:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#child1 {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
#child2 {
  flex: 1;
}
#child3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="background-color: pink;">
    <div id="child1" style="background-color: gray;">
        div1
    </div>

    <div id="child2" style="background-color: blue;">
        div2
    </div>

    <div id="child3" style="background-color: violet;">
        div3
    </div>
</div>
```

Some explanation:

1. Make `#parent`'s display as `flex`, start flex layout for all child elements.
2. Make `flex-direction` as `row`, make child elements displayed horizontally.
3. Make `#child2`'s `flex` as `1`, which means it will shrink or extend to occupy all available space in `#parent`.

Please note all inline `display` CSS rules are removed. They are not necessary once flex layout is enabled.